# I have a problem regarding extracting in python

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have been using the following code to extract the files:

```
import os, zipfile

extension = ".zip"

for item in os.listdir(dir_name): # loop through items in dir

if item.endswith(extension): # check for ".zip" extension

    file_name = os.path.abspath(item) # get full path of files

    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) # create zipfile object

    zip_ref.extractall(dir_name) # extract file to dir

    zip_ref.close() # close file

    os.remove(file_name) # delete
```

The problem is that all the files inside the zip have the same name. For example:

Zip 1 has names,
"File 1, File 2"

Whereas Zip 2 also has names "Files 1" and "File 2"

After extracting, all my files are getting overwritten by the next file.

Is there any solution to this?

I tried extracting files, expected the files to be extracted, but all the files got overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.mkdir("dir_name")` with the same name as the Zip File and then Extract them in this new directory `zip_ref.extractall("dir_name")`

For eg:- Zip File => my_zip.zip

```
filename = my_zip.zip
os.mkdir(filename.strip(".zip"))

#rest of the code

zip_ref.extractall(filename.strip(".zip"))
```

Comment: I need them inside the same directory for the next step.

Comment: Could you briefly tell, what kind of process you want to do after extraction?

Comment: All the zips have images inside them, i want to combine them all into a single pdf.

Comment: Maybe you can add them to the pdf first, then move on to extract the next zip file in the same loop?
OR
Use `os.rename(old_name, new_name)` to rename the files after extraction